# Magento 2 Type Error occurred when creating object: Wyomind\Framework\Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, log, critical

Magento 2.4 using when we are trying to log in from admin then we are getting this error -

```
    main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: 
Wyomind\Framework\Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result, Argument 6 passed to 

Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__construct() must be an instance of 

Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\JsonHexTag, null given, called in 
/var/www/html/mirafit_preprod_grum/mirafit/vendor/wyomind/framework/Magento/Ui/TemplateEn
gine/Xhtml/Result.php on line 79 [] []
```

Run all commands upgrade,compile,deploy and cache.

We just copy code from the production server to localhost
Is anyone aware of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps :

1. Check if your live server and local server configurations are same.
2. if yes then try remove vendor folder and composer install
3. If you have redis installed on your local try redis-cli FLUSHALL
4. Live and local php version should be same

Comment: Yes all is matching with live server.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because their module uses a stupidly poor architecture where the same file has different versions for each correspondent version of Magento ‍♂️

Locally it works because the setup:upgrade copies the files as needed and the developer mode does the rest, which doesn't happen on the server.

**Solution**: copy the files ending in _2.4.php (`find vendor/wyomind -iname '*_2.4.php'`) overriding their original, non-sufixed counterparts.

> Tip: composer patches can be created to accomplish that in all envs